# Node.JS Command Prompt

Tags: node.js, npm, command, command-prompt

I was messing around with the npm package today and I noticed that all of my commands were being run from my command prompt on my machine rather than through the node.js command line that comes with the download.

Bottom line: Why is there a node command prompt if you run commands from your local command prompt?

I saw there was a question like this here: [node.js command line tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784522/node-js-command-line-tool) but it doesnt exactly answer the question.

I appreciate any help out there.

Comment: The Node.js command prompt is just a cmd window set up to use Node and npm, there's also the REPL that runs Node commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node.js command prompt has your node.js environment set-up. Most of time, if you try to install some global package through your local command prompt, it will not work as expected, but if you use node.js command prompt it will. Happened to me while trying to use the express-generator.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  In this sense, is the node command prompt a better method of running commands, or should i just continue using my local command prompt?

Comment: You can use either as long as everything works fine. For npm related tasks, node command prompt is a better choice.